# Why can't I get the title of the youtube video by pafy

Tags: python, pafy

[image]Here is my code:

```
import pafy
v = pafy.new('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTOFksRBxeU')
v.title
```

I get the `_` for `v.title` instead of real video name, other items like `v.dislikes` works fine, why?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue Today.

I'm using same code so I just guess the structure of the youtube video is slightly changed.

BTW, You can choose one of titles listed below using if statement.

1. v.title
2. v._ydl_info.get('alt_title')
3. v.mix.title

In my case,

```
videoTitle = video.title
    print(videoTitle)
    if(videoTitle=='_'):
        videoTitle = video._ydl_info.get('alt_title')
        print(videoTitle)
        if(videoTitle==None):
            videoTitle = video.mix.title
            print(videoTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest version (python3.7) using pip:

```
pip3.7 install pafy==0.5.4 youtube-dl==2019.7.30
```

and running your example, I properly get the title:

```
>>> import pafy
>>> v = pafy.new('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTOFksRBxeU')
>>> v.title
'【妖怪ウォッチ４】日本最速実況で大爆笑www【ヒカキン&セイキン】'
```

What version are you using ? What kind of encoding your repl/editor uses ?

Comment: I am using python 3.6.1 and My pafy version is 0.5.4.

Comment: in this case, it must have something to do with your environment, not the libary. I don't see how we can help.